# How to use Ionic with Angular Tools in Ionic React?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

As a month ago, Ionic published their full version of "Ionic React". My personal experience with Ionic is based on Angular JS, so, how can I use Ionic with Angular JS in Ionic React or is it possible ?

Edit:As Angular JS is now on https://killedbygoogle.com , this topic has importance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have an understanding of reactjs to use Ionic React. Ionic has moved to Angular (2+) and recently to React and Vue as well. React works with Virtual DOM whereas Angularjs with Regular DOM. Also, language is also different. React uses JSX and Angularjs, javascript and HTML. Another interesting thing is that React is Library and Angularjs is a Framework.

So, I don't think using Angularjs with Ionic React makes much sense.

You should learn the basics of React if you want to work with Ionic React. If you to want to stick with Angular(2+) then you have to learn Typescript. As of today, Ionic Angular is more stable than Ionic React. Ionic React just got released and will take some time to get fully stable.

Comment: Okay, so, I should learn Ionic tutorials which are only available for Ionic with Angular Js, and then, I should learn reactjs and then combine my knowledge in plain Ionic and reactjs ?

Comment: You just need reactjs and capacitor. See [here](https://ionicframework.com/blog/announcing-ionic-react/). It is not recommended to use Ionic v1. Ionic has officially moved on from AngularJs. The latest official version of ionic is now 4. The official [doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/overview) will help you better understand how to start with Ionic React. I would say just learn the basics of Reactjs, that's all you need to start.

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on ionic since Ionic 2 and last year when Ionic 5 was released with React I switched to the new Tech Stack as React is Plain Javascript and much faster when it comes to the compilation and bundling as it doesn't have other not needed dependencies.
**Ok Here are some pointers to keep in mind when moving from Ionic (Angular) to Ionic (React) development.**

1. Ionic Doesn't support Cordova when it comes to React it uses Capacitor instead which has more boilerPlate when comes to implementation and Cordova has a bigger community + easy to integrate.
2. Also React is recently introduced therefore it is not that much stable.
3. Not Many people use  React with Ionic, therefore, won't be able to get solutions to the issues and have to fix them by yourself.
4. Lastly, Capacitor doest support all the native API for example "SplashScreen" which is the basic one.

   I have been working with it for the past 2 months and I can say Ionic(Cordova + Angular) was better.